# Cinnamon desktop, no shutdown button

Tags: shutdown, cinnamon

I am using Cinnamon desktop with 14.04. Since a couple of months, I am facing this issue. It is that there is no shutdown , restart or log off buttons when you click the shutdown button in pop up menu.

I am currently using **sudo shutdown -h now** to quit the session. I have Gnome desktop installed on same PC and I get the shutdown button there. Is there any fix to it ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I guess I found a work around. You need to right click on the panel and add a shutdown applet from the list available online

[image: Add shutdown button to Cinnamon]

Comment: For others in my situation, I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and my equivalent applet was named "User Applet" instead of "Shutdown Applet".

Answer (score 1):

This is not the exact solution to your problem, but rather a workaround. As an added bonus, using this workaround, you can shut down in one click instead of three.

> Setting up a Shutdown shortcut on your desktop is easy, but first you
>   must change the security of the executable, because in a fresh
>   install, it requires the root password to be used. Open a Terminal and
>   enter the following command:
>
> sudo chmod u+s /sbin/shutdown
>
> You will be prompted for your root password. After that, you're done
>   and can type "exit" to exit out of the Terminal.
>
> Next, on your Desktop, right-click on empty space somewhere and choose
>   to Create a Launcher. The type will be Application, which is the
>   default, and for the command, enter the following:
>
> shutdown -Ph now
>
> You may name it whatever you please, although my choice is one word, a
>   simple "Off", reflecting the universal term found on remote controls
>   and other appliances since time began. Under comments, you may wish to
>   note "Power down" or "Shut down" if you wish. To change the icon,
>   click on the springboard icon (which is the default), because we can
>   do better than that. I found an appropriate icon to suggest "Off"
>   located right here in Linux Mint 17:
>
> /usr/share/pixmaps/pidgin/emblems/scalable/unavailable.svg
>
> After you save this, try it out and see whether it works. Mine worked
>   right away without a hitch. For a challenge, you might try setting up
>   a launcher for Restart as well. You can find all the options available
>   for the shutdown command by opening a terminal and typing shutdown
>   --help.

Source: https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1113

Comment: Thank you. I see that this is for Linux Mint, will it work on Ubuntu as well ?

Comment: Ok. I was actually looking for a solution which will fix the DE to how it is supposed to. Will check this out any way. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Mint is based on Ubuntu so it should work there also.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue. The reason was, that apt has installed some updated in the background. After waiting, the shutdown button was back.

Maybe you have to force stop apt.